TestCafe equivalent of document.querySelectorAll()
I want to do the equivalent of this
document.querySelectorAll('.my-class').forEach(element => element.click())

in TestCafe. I.e. selecting multiple elements with a specific class and clicking on all of them. And I don't know how many elements there are in advance, so I can't use any hardcoded solution.
I've tried
test('My Test', async (t) => {
    const boxes = Selector('.my-class')

    const count = boxes.length // attempt 1
    // const count = boxes.count // attempt 2
    // const count = await boxes.count // attempt 3

    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        await t.click(boxes.nth(i))
    }
})

but no luck.
I've tried googling, looking at TestCafe's API, and asking ChatGPT but I can't seem to find anything regarding selecting multiple elements that share the same selector.

try this await t.click(boxes.withText('My Text').nth(i)); instead of await t.click(boxes.nth(i))

@ChrisG but the boxes may contain different text that I don't know ahead of time. I only know their position in the DOM and the class attributes etc.

Actually it turned out that attempt 3 did, in fact, work... I had just mistakenly used the wrong selector string.
So this works:
test('My Test', async (t) => {
    const boxes = Selector('.my-CORRECT-class')

    const count = await boxes.count

    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        await t.click(boxes.nth(i))
    }
})

The .count property is a promise so that's why you have to await it (even if you were to await Selector).
